# Text Area / Input fields only get partial text filled in on Samasung s3 in chrome / webview

Tags: android, input, webview, textarea

We observed a very strange bug with our app on the samsung s3 (running android 4.0.4 )

When typing text into a text area only the first character of each word would fill in, and only after you pressed space or picked a word from predictive text.

Typing 'what the hell ..' would result in 'w t h' being entered in the text area

Other text areas on different screens were working fine.

Turning off predictive text also fixed the issue.

Has anyone run into this issue before?

Answer (score 0):

After further investigation we noticed that the problematic textarea wasn't changing appearance when it got focus - all our working text fields turned into square cornered fields with orange borders when clicked.

It turns out android does something odd and dynamically replaces your input fields with native elements as they get focus (hence the un-style-able orange bordered square bits :( ).

the kicker - if your input is inside an element with css absolute positioning this fails, and this also seems to mess up some forms of keyboard input. setting the element (and parent elements) to use position static fixes the issue.

We only saw this on the s3 when predictive text was on (this is the default..) but it may be on other devices.

Chalk this one up to Androids browser still being a mess..

Note that using this css hack to stop the native elements from being substituted:

```
 input:focus { -webkit-user-modify: read-write-plaintext-only; }
```

caused ALL our text fields to have the problem outlined in this thread.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem too for a long time but have found that the key to stopping this glitch is to turn off the predictive text option in the keyboard settings every time you experience the 1st character input only problem. Personally, I like the predictive text being on 99% of the time, but some web pages (email providers mainly) aren't configured for predictive text to be used, so I keep predictive text on & just turn it off whenever I come across a web page where I experience the 1st character input only problem. To turn it on/off simply hit the cog button on the keyboard & where it says predictive text, just swipe the slider to the left, to the off position. This will allow whole words to be typed instead of just 1 character at a time. Then, once you've finished typing, you can hit the cog again & turn predictive text back on.